# I got this exception with VeeValidate : Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I'm new to Vee Validate. Here is my code, which actually can't be more simple :

```
<div id = "app">

{{ message }}

                        <Form @submit="onSubmit">

                            <label>Type de client :</label>&nbsp;
                            <Field name="email" type="email" />

                        </Form>

                    </div>


                    <script type="importmap">
                        {
                          "imports": {
                            "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js",
                            "@vue/devtools-api": "https://unpkg.com/@vue/devtools-api@6.4.5/lib/esm/index.js"

                          }
                        }
                      </script>

                        <script type="module">

                            import { createApp } from 'vue';
                            import { Form, Field } from './node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js';

                                createApp({

                                    data() 
                                    {
                                        return {

                                            message: 'Hello Vue!',

                                            
                                        }
                                    }

                                    ,

                                    methods:
                                    {

                                        onSubmit(values) {
                                            alert(values);
                                        }

                                    }

                                    ,

                                    components: {
                                     Form,
                                     Field
                                    }

                                }).mount('#app')


                        </script>
```

But in the Chrome console I got :

```
vee-validate.esm.js:1701 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at _useField (vee-validate.esm.js:1701:5)
    at useField (vee-validate.esm.js:1565:12)
    at setup (vee-validate.esm.js:2011:164)
    at callWithErrorHandling (vue.esm-browser.js:1628:18)
    at setupStatefulComponent (vue.esm-browser.js:8625:25)
    at setupComponent (vue.esm-browser.js:8586:36)
    at mountComponent (vue.esm-browser.js:7000:7)
    at processComponent (vue.esm-browser.js:6966:9)
    at patch (vue.esm-browser.js:6452:11)
    at mountChildren (vue.esm-browser.js:6696:7)
```

The process variable seems to be undefined. So I guess I need to import something somewhere, but according to the tutorial

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/overview/

I don't need anything else.

Any clue?

Thanks